# Webtrc Freeswitch

Tags: webrtc, freeswitch, jssip

Trying get together Freeswitch + WebRTC + RTMP + jsSIP.
For NAT traversal i'm using STUN servers.
In Chrome all is fine, but in FF have one way sound. In tcpdump I'm dont see RTP from freeswitch to abonent. But see rtp to freeswitch. And I'm have similar situation with RTMP in FF. Have any ideas?
This is my logs:

```
Freeswitch debug:

    freeswitch@internal> 2015-03-05 15:24:04.764229 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1055 New Channel sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [91822106-c375-11e4-ae79-0dedd8f6626f]
2015-03-05 15:24:04.764229 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1061 Send signal sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [BREAK]
2015-03-05 15:24:04.764229 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1061 Send signal sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [BREAK]
2015-03-05 15:24:04.764229 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:472 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) Running State Change CS_NEW
2015-03-05 15:24:04.764229 [DEBUG] sofia.c:8844 sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 receiving invite from 195.54.42.58:51524 version: 1.5.15b git 3a70750 2015-03-04 19:06:18Z 64bit
2015-03-05 15:24:04.764229 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1061 Send signal sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [BREAK]
2015-03-05 15:24:04.764229 [DEBUG] sofia.c:2065 detaching session 91822106-c375-11e4-ae79-0dedd8f6626f
2015-03-05 15:24:04.764229 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:491 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) State NEW
2015-03-05 15:24:05.024229 [DEBUG] sofia.c:2173 Re-attaching to session 91822106-c375-11e4-ae79-0dedd8f6626f
2015-03-05 15:24:05.024229 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1061 Send signal sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [BREAK]
2015-03-05 15:24:05.024229 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1061 Send signal sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [BREAK]
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] sofia.c:8844 sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 receiving invite from 195.54.42.58:51524 version: 1.5.15b git 3a70750 2015-03-04 19:06:18Z 64bit
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_xml.c:2008 Cache Info
Time Now:       1425587045044232
Expires:        1425586902484231
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_xml.c:2010 Cache expired for 97487336@172.31.47.5, doing fresh lookup
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_xml.c:2088 caching lookup for user 97487336@172.31.47.5 for 0 milliseconds
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] sofia.c:10109 Setting NAT mode based on websockets
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6623 Channel sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 entering state [received][100]
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6633 Remote SDP:
v=0
o=Mozilla-SIPUA-35.0.1 3612 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=SIP Call
t=0 0
a=ice-ufrag:8ea45330
a=ice-pwd:4e78b1d5d159b6ee310a347e052ee5f9
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D7:50:B9:35:92:DB:35:2F:49:52:DC:AD:98:7F:6E:EA:C0:D3:B4:81:EB:E4:93:BF:A5:97:EC:DC:10:FC:DF:72
m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ptime:20
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=setup:actpass
a=rtcp-mux
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 192.168.1.101 52871 typ host
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 192.168.1.101 52872 typ host
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1692467199 195.54.42.58 64326 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 52871
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1692467198 195.54.42.58 64107 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 52872

2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6899 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) State Change CS_NEW -> CS_INIT
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1396 Send signal sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [BREAK]
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:472 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) Running State Change CS_INIT
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:512 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) State INIT
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:87 sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 SOFIA INIT
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:40 sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 Standard INIT
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:48 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) State Change CS_INIT -> CS_ROUTING
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1396 Send signal sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [BREAK]
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:512 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) State INIT going to sleep
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:472 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) Running State Change CS_ROUTING
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:2184 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) Callstate Change DOWN -> RINGING
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:528 (sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157) State ROUTING
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:123 sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 SOFIA ROUTING
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:166 sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 Standard ROUTING
2015-03-05 15:24:05.044232 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:635 Processing 97487336 <97487336>->wrtc_24088503 in context default
2015-03-05 15:24:06.324312 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1061 Send signal sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157 [BREAK]
2015-03-05 15:24:06.324312 [NOTICE] mod_sofia.c:2107 Ring-Ready sofia/internal/97487336@52.11.173.157!


Content-Length: 0




" " +228ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"message" "Registered" voip.js:382
"status.active" Arguments { 0: "status.active", ещё 2… } voip.js:25
"JsSIP:Transport " "received WebSocket text message:

NOTIFY sip:4em2vv3j@onkt63k1mjvi.invalid;transport=ws SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS 52.11.173.157:5066;rport;branch=z9hG4bKaaQUBj83F53yK

Route: <sip:4em2vv3j@195.54.42.58:52764>;transport=ws

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=r9gyFg2Nr962m

To: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>

Call-ID: 0e6acf51-3e18-1233-2f9a-0267945f27aa

CSeq: 72457382 NOTIFY

Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@52.11.173.157:5060>

User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.15b+git~20150304T190618Z~3a70750b42~64bit

Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE

Supported: path, replaces

Event: message-summary

Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer

Subscription-State: terminated;reason=noresource

Content-Type: application/simple-message-summary

Content-Length: 67



Messages-Waiting: no

Message-Account: sip:97487336@172.31.47.5




" " +64ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "sending WebSocket message:

SIP/2.0 405 Method Not Allowed

Via: SIP/2.0/WS 52.11.173.157:5066;rport;branch=z9hG4bKaaQUBj83F53yK

To: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=9cvrud8hud

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=r9gyFg2Nr962m

Call-ID: 0e6acf51-3e18-1233-2f9a-0267945f27aa

CSeq: 72457382 NOTIFY

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS

Supported: outbound

Content-Length: 0




" " +8ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:NonInviteServerTransaction " "Timer J expired for transaction z9hG4bKaaQUBj83F53yK" " +30ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"callUp.before" Arguments { 0: "callUp.before", 1: 12, 2: undefined, ещё 2… } voip.js:25
"api.call.begin" Arguments { 0: "api.call.begin", 1: Object, 2: VoIP</GUI_pv.prototype.apiCallBegin/<(), ещё 2… } voip.js:25
"API create call response" Object { result: true, outCallId: 111, inCallId: 222 } voip.js:376
"status.inactive" Arguments { 0: "status.inactive", ещё 2… } voip.js:25
"init" Arguments { 0: "init", 1: Object, ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"JsSIP " "version 0.6.18" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja " "version 0.5.0" " +3ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja " "detected browser: Firefox 35.0 [mobile:false, tablet:false, android:false, ios:false]" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "configuration parameters after validation:" " +65ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- via_host: "v3esbi87ujtn.invalid"" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- password: NOT SHOWN" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- register_expires: 600" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- register: false" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- registrar_server: sip:52.11.173.157" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- ws_server_max_reconnection: 3" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- ws_server_reconnection_timeout: 4" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- connection_recovery_min_interval: 2" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- connection_recovery_max_interval: 30" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- use_preloaded_route: false" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- no_answer_timeout: 30000" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- session_timers: false" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- hack_via_tcp: false" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- hack_via_ws: false" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- hack_ip_in_contact: false" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- node_websocket_options: {}" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- uri: sip:97487336@52.11.173.157" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- ws_servers: [{"ws_uri":"ws://52.11.173.157:5066","sip_uri":"<sip:52.11.173.157:5066;transport=ws;lr>","weight":0,"status":0,"scheme":"WS"}]" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- instance_id: "cda27030-e4d7-405e-a8f8-7961814b0c2b"" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- jssip_id: "13942"" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- hostport_params: "52.11.173.157"" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "- authorization_user: "97487336"" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja " "WebRTC supported" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:UA " "start()" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "connecting to WebSocket ws://52.11.173.157:5066" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
GET http://52.11.173.157:5066/ [HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols 430мс]
"JsSIP:Transport " "WebSocket ws://52.11.173.157:5066 connected" " +500ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"message" "Connection success" popup.js:382
"ready" Arguments { 0: "ready", 1: Object, ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"callUp.before" Arguments { 0: "callUp.before", 1: "wrtc_24088503", 2: "Alex 2", ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"callUp_before" "Alex 2" popup.js:376
"message" "Give access to your microphone" popup.js:382
"JsSIP:UA " "call()" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "new" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "connect()" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "new | pcConfig:" " +7ms" Object { iceServers: Array[1] } jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "setConfigurationAndOptions | processed pcConfig:" " +0ms" Object { iceServers: Array[1] } jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "newRTCSession" " +150ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"debug" "newRTCSession" Object { originator: "local", session: Object, request: Object } popup.js:376
"debug" "add session" Object { ua: Object, status: 0, dialog: null, earlyDialogs: Object, connection: Object, is_confirmed: false, late_sdp: false, rtcOfferConstraints: null, rtcAnswerConstraints: null, localMediaStream: null, ещё 24… } popup.js:376
"rtcninja:Adapter " "getUserMedia() | constraints:" " +0ms" Object { audio: true, video: false } jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"callUp" Arguments { 0: "callUp", ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"rtcninja:Adapter " "getUserMedia() | success" " +2s" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "addStream() | stream:" " +0ms" LocalMediaStream { currentTime: 0 } jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "session connecting" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"message" "Connecting with user..." popup.js:382
"outgoingCall.connect" Arguments { 0: "outgoingCall.connect", ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "createLocalDescription()" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "createOffer()" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "createOffer() | success" " +2ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "setLocalDescription()" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "setLocalDescription() | success" " +10ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "sending WebSocket message:

INVITE sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9913060

Max-Forwards: 69

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9521 INVITE

Contact: <sip:aake2452@v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;transport=ws;ob>

Content-Type: application/sdp

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS

Supported: ice,outbound

User-Agent: JsSIP 0.6.18

Content-Length: 871



v=0

o=Mozilla-SIPUA-35.0.1 18073 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=SIP Call

t=0 0

a=ice-ufrag:c2ab2cd2

a=ice-pwd:49ebd6ec4e8cd8dff4d90fbb1db04feb

a=fingerprint:sha-256 12:CE:48:7D:B4:2C:FB:03:C4:DF:F5:0E:7D:E7:02:DF:0A:5D:06:A8:99:41:82:D4:91:79:4F:7D:BC:53:3A:0F

m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2

a=ptime:20

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-15

a=sendrecv

a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level

a=setup:actpass

a=rtcp-mux

a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 192.168.1.101 55983 typ host

a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 192.168.1.101 55984 typ host

a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1692467199 195.54.42.58 53117 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 55983

a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1692467198 195.54.42.58 60365 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 55984


" " +3ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "onsignalingstatechange() | signalingState: have-local-offer" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "onicecandidate() | m0(no mid) candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 192.168.1.101 55983 typ host" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "onicecandidate() | m0(no mid) candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 192.168.1.101 55984 typ host" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "onicecandidate() | m0(no mid) candidate:1 1 UDP 1692467199 195.54.42.58 53117 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 55983" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "onicecandidate() | m0(no mid) candidate:1 2 UDP 1692467198 195.54.42.58 60365 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 55984" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "onicecandidate() | end of candidates" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9913060;received=195.54.42.58;rport=63980

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9521 INVITE

User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.15b+git~20150304T190618Z~3a70750b42~64bit

Content-Length: 0




" " +343ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "receiveInviteResponse()" " +16ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9913060;received=195.54.42.58;rport=63980

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>;tag=SjaQHBKSNjXNg

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9521 INVITE

User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.15b+git~20150304T190618Z~3a70750b42~64bit

Accept: application/sdp

Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE

Supported: path, replaces

Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer

Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="52.11.173.157", nonce="3c76ea02-c375-11e4-ae53-0dedd8f6626f", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"

Content-Length: 0




" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9913060

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>;tag=SjaQHBKSNjXNg

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9521 ACK

Content-Length: 0




" " +9ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "sending WebSocket message:

INVITE sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK1611429

Max-Forwards: 69

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9522 INVITE

Proxy-Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="97487336", realm="52.11.173.157", nonce="3c76ea02-c375-11e4-ae53-0dedd8f6626f", uri="sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157", response="efbefd849d15b696cac323f507bba3b2", qop=auth, cnonce="m7lmpr5toqpg", nc=00000001

Contact: <sip:aake2452@v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;transport=ws;ob>

Content-Type: application/sdp

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS

Supported: ice,outbound

User-Agent: JsSIP 0.6.18

Content-Length: 871



v=0

o=Mozilla-SIPUA-35.0.1 18073 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=SIP Call

t=0 0

a=ice-ufrag:c2ab2cd2

a=ice-pwd:49ebd6ec4e8cd8dff4d90fbb1db04feb

a=fingerprint:sha-256 12:CE:48:7D:B4:2C:FB:03:C4:DF:F5:0E:7D:E7:02:DF:0A:5D:06:A8:99:41:82:D4:91:79:4F:7D:BC:53:3A:0F

m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2

a=ptime:20

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-15

a=sendrecv

a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level

a=setup:actpass

a=rtcp-mux

a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 192.168.1.101 55983 typ host

a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 192.168.1.101 55984 typ host

a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1692467199 195.54.42.58 53117 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 55983

a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1692467198 195.54.42.58 60365 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.101 rport 55984


" " +7ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:InviteClientTransaction " "Timer D expired for transaction z9hG4bK9913060" " +9ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK1611429;received=195.54.42.58;rport=63980

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9522 INVITE

User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.15b+git~20150304T190618Z~3a70750b42~64bit


Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:ko6rfc61@52.11.173.157>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no



v=0

o=FreeSWITCH 1425563378 1425563379 IN IP4 52.11.173.157

s=FreeSWITCH

c=IN IP4 52.11.173.157

t=0 0

a=msid-semantic: WMS 3PGsZhhNXHqvPSeURXN5yj0IJyB878R0

m=audio 23534 RTP/SAVPF 109 101

a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2

a=fmtp:109 useinbandfec=1; usedtx=1; maxaveragebitrate=30000; maxplaybackrate=48000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=ptime:20

a=fingerprint:sha-256 83:B1:D9:44:9A:17:DE:13:36:24:E3:1F:D8:0E:A0:86:77:25:5B:53:80:13:C3:F0:96:E8:34:32:AC:EE:CE:16

a=rtcp-mux

a=rtcp:23534 IN IP4 52.11.173.157

a=ssrc:2768117494 cname:OojEwrhkYyFDgJoY

a=ssrc:2768117494 msid:3PGsZhhNXHqvPSeURXN5yj0IJyB878R0 a0

a=ssrc:2768117494 mslabel:3PGsZhhNXHqvPSeURXN5yj0IJyB878R0

a=ssrc:2768117494 label:3PGsZhhNXHqvPSeURXN5yj0IJyB878R0a0

a=ice-ufrag:w1TVaKtK8VJ5TrWy

a=ice-pwd:F621nabbyHFFhTtDLdpMNImL

a=candidate:4434570021 1 udp 659136 52.11.173.157 23534 typ host generation 0


" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "receiveInviteResponse()" " +9ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "sendRequest()" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession:Request " "new | ACK" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6630835

Max-Forwards: 69

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>;tag=tU3FK63vjUK8B

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9522 ACK

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS

Supported: outbound

User-Agent: JsSIP 0.6.18

Content-Length: 0




" " +4ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
POST http://q76.queuev4.vk.com/im503 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2197мс]
"Alex 1: 00:00:01" voip.js:382
"Alex 1: 00:00:02" voip.js:382
"Alex 1: 00:00:03" voip.js:382
POST http://q76.queuev4.vk.com/im503 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25053мс]
"Alex 1: 00:00:04" voip.js:382
"Alex 1: 00:00:05" voip.js:382
"Alex 1: 00:00:06" voip.js:382
"Alex 1: 00:00:07" voip.js:382
"Alex 1: 00:00:08" voip.js:382
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "setRemoteDescription() | success" " +9s" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "session accepted" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"debug" "call accepted" Object { originator: "remote", response: Object } popup.js:376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "sendRequest()" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession:Request " "new | ACK" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK4020045

Max-Forwards: 69

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>;tag=tU3FK63vjUK8B

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9522 ACK

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS

Supported: outbound

User-Agent: JsSIP 0.6.18

Content-Length: 0




" " +4ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "session confirmed" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"debug" "call confirmed" Object { originator: "local", ack: null } popup.js:376
"message" "Speaking..." popup.js:382
"outgoingCall.speak" Arguments { 0: "outgoingCall.speak", 1: "Alex 2", ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "onsignalingstatechange() | signalingState: stable" " +2ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"hangUp.before" Arguments { 0: "hangUp.before", 1: Object, ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"debug" "hang up" Object { ua: Object, status: 8, earlyDialogs: Object, connection: Object, is_confirmed: true, late_sdp: false, rtcOfferConstraints: null, rtcAnswerConstraints: null, localMediaStream: LocalMediaStream, localMediaStreamLocallyGenerated: true, ещё 23… } popup.js:376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "terminate()" " +12s" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "terminating session" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "sendRequest()" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession:Request " "new | BYE" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Transport " "sending WebSocket message:

BYE sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8019990

Max-Forwards: 69

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>;tag=tU3FK63vjUK8B

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9523 BYE

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS

Supported: outbound

User-Agent: JsSIP 0.6.18

Content-Length: 0




" " +7ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "session ended" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "close()" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "close()" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "oniceconnectionstatechange() | iceConnectionState: closed" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession " "close() | closing local MediaStream" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"rtcninja:Adapter " "closeMediaStream() | calling stop() on all the MediaStreamTrack" " +1ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:Dialog " "dialog 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0i9oi2j4lsitU3FK63vjUK8B deleted" " +0ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"ENDED:" Arguments { 0: Object, ещё 2… } popup.js:738
"debug" "call ended" Object { originator: "local", message: null, cause: "Rejected" } popup.js:376
"message" "Call ended" popup.js:382
"outgoingCall.end" Arguments { 0: "outgoingCall.end", ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"Call ended, duration 00:00:11" popup.js:382
"hangUp" Arguments { 0: "hangUp", ещё 2… } popup.js:25
"rtcninja:RTCPeerConnection " "onsignalingstatechange() | signalingState: closed" " +22ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"popup.call.end" Arguments { 0: "popup.call.end", 1: Object, ещё 2… } voip.js:25
"api.call.end" Arguments { 0: "api.call.end", 1: "{"outCallId":"111","inCallId":"222","callerId":"11","clientId":"12"}", 2: VoIP</GUI_pv.prototype.apiCallEnd/<(), ещё 2… } voip.js:25
"API update history response" "send request to /call/updateHistory" voip.js:376
"JsSIP:Transport " "received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/WS v3esbi87ujtn.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8019990;received=195.54.42.58;rport=63980

From: <sip:97487336@52.11.173.157>;tag=i9oi2j4lsi

To: <sip:wrtc_24088503@52.11.173.157>;tag=tU3FK63vjUK8B

Call-ID: 13942n4ifccgdi8s0rr0

CSeq: 9523 BYE

User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.15b+git~20150304T190618Z~3a70750b42~64bit

Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE

Supported: path, replaces

Content-Length: 0




" " +432ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:RTCSession:Request " "onSuccessResponse" " +11ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"JsSIP:InviteClientTransaction " "Timer B expired for transaction z9hG4bK1611429" " +21ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"ENDED:" Arguments { 0: Object, ещё 2… } voip.js:710
"debug" "call ended" Object { originator: "remote", message: Object, cause: "Terminated" } voip.js:376
"message" "Call ended" voip.js:382
"incomingCall.end" Arguments { 0: "incomingCall.end", ещё 2… } voip.js:25
"JsSIP:UA " "stop()" " +627ms" jssip-0.6.18.js:21376
"destroy" Arguments { 0: "destroy", 1: Object, ещё 2… } popup.js:25
GET http://cs7-3v4.vk-cdn.net/p13/be7e2d819d42f3.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2851мс]
POST http://q76.queuev4.vk.com/im503 
POST http://vk.com/audio [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1301мс]
```

Regards Alex

Comment: It looks like FF is only offering audio in its SDP. Does it grab the camera ok with `getusermedia`?

Answer (score 0):

The mod_verto implementation is much better than the WebRTC one.  I would recommend going down that route from experience.

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_verto

Answer (score 0):

I known a tool to test media resources on current browser. You can use it to make sure media resources work well first.

https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/echotest.html

Comment: Always add essential part of the link into answer.

Comment: Thank for your tips @serenesat

Answer (score 0):

from https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_verto:

> although Firefox is a good web browser, **it does not support stereo WebRTC audio**, therefore the stereo positioning will be lost on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem in the Firefox because they decreased the support for webrtc in the updated version of Firefox.

Try with lower version of Firefox (42).